# Problemas al eliminar un objeto seleccionado de una Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, consola, eliminar

tengo un problema con un método (devolverReserva()) que me debería eliminar un objeto (en mi caso una Reserva) de dos Arraylist diferentes. El método lo primero que hace es pedir el teléfono y el mail de un Usuario y después el ISBN del libro que quiere devolver. El problema que encuentro es que a la hora de querer eliminar el libro de las listas de reserva (una general y otra especifica del Usuario) no elimina nada. ¿Qué debería hacer para que se elimine el libro de las dos ArrayList?

Esta es la clase usuario y su constructor:

```
public class Usuario extends Persona {
private Integer telefono;
private String direccion;
private Integer codigoPostal;
private String correoElectronico;
private List<Reserva> listaReserva;

public Usuario() {

}

public Usuario(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, Integer edad, Integer telefono, String direccion, Integer codigoPostal, String correoElectronico, List<Reserva> listaReserva) {
    super(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad);
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
    this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico;
    this.listaReserva = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

En el constructor necesitamos que el this.listaReserva = new ArrayList<>(); no cambie porque es necesario que este así para nuestro método reservarLibro()

Los valores que tengo en el Main:

```
//usuarios:
usuarioArrayList.add(new Usuario("Paco", "Martinez", "Pedro", 55, 758451267, "Calle 13", 07003, "pacomartinez@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));
usuarioArrayList.add(new Usuario("Pamela", "Mejia", "Fontseca", 20, 68849026, "Calle Blanquerna", 07777, "pamelamejia@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));

//libros:
libroarraylist.add(new Libro("002a", "El principito", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "Editoriales Ignatius", 5, 2));
libroarraylist.add(new Libro("003a", "50 Sombras de Grey", "Sam Taylor-Wood", "Editoriales Maitus", 5, 5));
```

Esta es la clase Reserva:

```
public class Reserva {
    private Libro libro;
    private Date fechaReserva;
}
```

Y este es el método:

```
    public static void devolverlibro(ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios, ArrayList<Libro> libroArrayList, ArrayList<Reserva> reservaArrayList) {
        System.out.print("\n Introduce tu telefono: ");
        Scanner leer1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer telefono = Integer.parseInt(leer1.nextLine());
        System.out.print("\n Introduce tu email: ");
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String email = leer.nextLine();
        int compro = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {
            if (usuarios.get(i).getTelefono().equals(telefono) && usuarios.get(i).getCorreoElectronico().equals(email)) {
                System.out.println("\n" + "Acceso correcto");
                System.out.print("\n ISBN a buscar: ");
                Scanner leer3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String isbn = leer3.nextLine();
                int comprobante = 1;
                for (int contador = 0; contador < libroArrayList.size(); contador++) {
                    if (libroArrayList.get(contador).getIsbn().equals(isbn) && libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() < libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopias()) {

                        reservaArrayList.remove(libroArrayList.get(contador));
                        libroArrayList.get(contador).setNumCopiasDisponibles(libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() + 1);
                        usuarios.get(i).getListaReserva().remove(libroArrayList.get(contador));
                        comprobante = 0;
                        compro = 0;
                        System.out.println(reservaArrayList);
                        System.out.println(usuarios);

                        contador = libroArrayList.size();
                        i = usuarios.size();
                    }
                }
                if (comprobante == 1) {
                    System.out.println("El libro no esta reservado");
                }
            }

        }
        if (compro == 1) {
            System.out.println("No es correcto");

        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, no hay método devolverReserva(), te sugerimos revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El inconveniente está en la forma que se eliminan los elementos, se está haciendo por referencia y con lo indicado en el código se puede interpretar que los objetos almacenados en las listas NO son los mismos, por esa razón es como si no existiese el dato pasado por parámetro a los métodos "remove".

Al poblar las listas se crean objetos con diferente referencia.

```
//usuarios:
usuarioArrayList.add(new Usuario("Paco", "Martinez", "Pedro", 55, 758451267, "Calle 13", 07003, "pacomartinez@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));
usuarioArrayList.add(new Usuario("Pamela", "Mejia", "Fontseca", 20, 68849026, "Calle Blanquerna", 07777, "pamelamejia@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));

//libros:
libroarraylist.add(new Libro("002a", "El principito", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "Editoriales Ignatius", 5, 2));
libroarraylist.add(new Libro("003a", "50 Sombras de Grey", "Sam Taylor-Wood", "Editoriales Maitus", 5, 5));

reservaArrayList.remove(libroArrayList.get(contador));
usuarios.get(i).getListaReserva().remove(libroArrayList.get(contador));
```

libroArrayList NO contiene los mismos objetos que reservaArrayList y usuarios.get(i).getListaReserva(), para el caso debería eliminarse por índice o buscar primero el objeto correspondiente para así poder eliminar por referencia específica. Adjunto un fragmento que espero pueda ayudar.

```
private static void versionUno() {
    List<Libro> listaLibrosUno = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Libro> listaLibrosDos = new ArrayList<>();

    listaLibrosUno.add(new Libro("Libro 1"));

    listaLibrosDos.add(new Libro("Libro 1"));

    listaLibrosUno.remove(listaLibrosDos.get(0));

    System.out.println(listaLibrosUno);
    System.out.println(listaLibrosDos);
}

private static void versionDos() {
    List<Libro> listaLibrosUno = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Libro> listaLibrosDos = new ArrayList<>();

    Libro libro = new Libro("Libro 1");
    listaLibrosUno.add(libro);

    listaLibrosDos.add(libro);

    listaLibrosUno.remove(listaLibrosDos.get(0));

    System.out.println(listaLibrosUno);
    System.out.println(listaLibrosDos);
}

private static void versionTres() {
    List<Libro> listaLibrosUno = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Libro> listaLibrosDos = new ArrayList<>();

    listaLibrosUno.add(new Libro("Libro 1"));

    listaLibrosDos.add(new Libro("Libro 1"));

    // Buscar referencia en lista uno para poder eliminarlo
    Libro libro = listaLibrosUno.stream().filter(l -> listaLibrosDos.get(0).nombre.equals(l.nombre)).findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

    listaLibrosUno.remove(libro);

    System.out.println(listaLibrosUno);
    System.out.println(listaLibrosDos);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Versión uno");
    versionUno();

    System.out.println("Versión dos");
    versionDos();

    System.out.println("Versión tres");
    versionTres();
}
```

Resultado:

Versión uno
[nombre: Libro 1]
[nombre: Libro 1]

Versión dos
[]
[nombre: Libro 1]

Versión tres
[]
[nombre: Libro 1]

Answer (score 0):

Estás confundido ya que estás recorriendo un arraayList de Libros llamado **libroArrayList**.
Lo que indicas es remover un objeto de un listado existente que es **reservaArrayList**, entonces aquí necesitarás un for para remover y otro para agregar al inventario.

```
for (int contador = 0; contador < reservaArrayList.size(); contador++) {
  if (reservaArrayList.get(contador).getIsbn().equals(isbn)) {
       reservaArrayList.remove(contador); //Removemos de la lista de reserva
       break; //Salimos del for
  }
}
```

Posteriormente agregamos el libro devuelto al inventario.

```
for (int contador = 0; contador < libroArrayList.size(); contador++) {
   if (libroArrayList.get(contador).getIsbn().equals(isbn)) {   libroArrayList.get(contador).setNumCopiasDisponibles(libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() + 1);
                        //usuarios.get(i).getListaReserva().remove(libroArrayList.get(contador)); Esta linea no se que hace pero siento que ya no es necesario, en todo caso si quieres asignar la lista de reserva a un usuario vamos a poner la siguiente linea.

   usuarios.get(i).setListaReserva(reservaArrayList);

                        comprobante = 0;
                        compro = 0;
                        System.out.println(reservaArrayList);
                        System.out.println(usuarios);

                        contador = libroArrayList.size();
                        i = usuarios.size();
                    }
                }
```